# ffmpeg OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid when converted to exe

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyinstaller

I am trying to merge a video file with an audio file, using FFmpeg. It work fine when I am testing it but when I make an exe file via pyinstaller and including the FFmpeg.exe inside there is a peculiar error I am getting.

> OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

This only happens when I set the FFmpeg run(quiet=True) but when I set the quiet=False everything works fine. The only problem is it shows the output window of FFmpeg.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
   application_path = sys._MEIPASS
elif __file__:
   application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ffmpegName = 'ffmpeg.exe'
ffmpegPath = os.path.join(application_path, ffmpegName)
video_stream = ffmpeg.input(file[0])
audio_stream = ffmpeg.input(file[1])
ffmpeg.output(audio_stream, video_stream, path).run(overwrite_output=True,
              cmd=ffmpegPath, quiet=True) #setting quiet=false everything works fine.
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here?
(Note the code is running in a different thread.)

Comment: If output window of FFmpeg is the only window being shown in your application then you can try using  --noconsole argument with your pyinstaller command.

Comment: I am using this in my spec debug=False, strip=False, upx=True, console=False , windowed=True  but without quiet=True inside run it shows up

Comment: Try with windowed=False

Comment: I am using QT Window so when I set windowed=False. exe fales to open